# Swift: Escaping closure How to pass values to previous ViewController after success

Tags: ios, swift, escaping, closures

I am using @escaping closure to run functions
All i want to pass the success dictionary to my previous ViewController to use its data.
Here is my code

```
func addToCart(vc:UIViewController, param:[String:String], completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ errorC : Error?, _ stock_flag : Bool?) -> Void)
    {
WebServiceHelper.sharedInstanceAPI.hitPostAPI(urlString: KeyConstant.APIAddCart, params: pramaTemp, completionHandler: { (result: [String:Any], err:Error?) in
            print(result)
            MBProgress().hideIndicator(view: vc.view)
            if(!(err == nil))
            {
                completionHandler(false,err, false)
                return
            }
            let json = JSON(result)
            
            let statusCode = json["status"].string
            print(json)
            if(statusCode == "success")
            {
                print(result)
                
                completionHandler(true,err,true)
            }
            else
            {
                if(json["stock_flag"].string == "0")
                {
                    completionHandler(false,err,false)
                }
                else if(json["stock_flag"].int == 0)
                {
                    completionHandler(false,err,false)
                }
                else
                {
                    completionHandler(false,err,true)
                }
            }
        })
        
    }
```

I got Success in response. Please guide me how i pass the result data to my previous `ViewController`.

I am using this code to navigate to model view where i am using the above code

```
CartViewModel().addToCart(vc: self, param:params ) { (isDone:Bool, error:Error?, stock_flag:Bool?) in
```

Comment: You don't need to give a reference to your ViewController into that method, since you only use it for hiding the MBProgress. The View could do that by himself in the response closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the dictionary to your success closure like this:

```
func addToCart(vc:UIViewController, param:[String:String], completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ errorC : Error?, _ stock_flag : Bool?, result: [String:Any]?) -> Void)
{ ... }
```

Afterwards you can just use it in the closure.

```
CartViewModel().addToCart(vc: self, param:params ) { (isDone, error, stock_flag, result) in 
    // Use result here
}
```